# Confusion with Enum#detect `nil` output

Tags: ruby

[`enum#detect`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable#detect-instance_method) says :

> Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block is not false. If no object matches, calls ifnone and returns its result when it is specified, or returns nil otherwise.

Now i was trying the below:

```
nil.call
#NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
#       from (irb):13
#       from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'


(1..10).detect(x = 2) { |i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }
#NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for 2:Fixnum
#       from (irb):15:in `detect'
#       from (irb):15
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Now my question is why the same error not occurred for the below:

```
(1..10).detect(x = nil) { |i| i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }
#=> nil
(1..10).detect(x = nil) { |i| p x; i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0 }
#nil
#nil
#nil
#nil
#nil
#nil
#nil
#nil
#nil
#nil
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the `detect` method (click 'View Source' on the documentation page), you'll see that it only tries to perform `call` if the parameter is **not** `nil`:

```
if (!NIL_P(if_none)) {
  return rb_funcall(if_none, id_call, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yes! you are right, I didn't see that source code, as sometimes these `C` codes are not being understood by me. :(

Comment: Could you join here please - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27184/ruby-conceptual?

Answer (score 0):

> If no object matches, calls ifnone and returns its result when it is specified, or returns nil otherwise.

I think you're parsing that sentence differently than it was intended. What is meant here is:

```
if no object matches
  if ifnone is set
    return ifnone.call
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

If you pass in `nil` as the argument, that counts as `ifnone` not being set, so it is not called. It will only be called if you pass a value other than `nil` for it.

Comment: I set `x = nil`, then how? if you see the last code output,the all `nil` output comes as output. that means `x` is set to `nil`.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu Yes, `x` is set to `nil` because you set to `nil`. I don't really understand your question. Note that `foo(x=bar)` is the same as `x=bar; foo(x)`.

Comment: humm I got the answer from another answer.I meant to say that `nil.call` not supported,but why the last code succeeded?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu In what way does the last code succeed? It prints nil a lot because you put `p x` in the block and `x` is `nil`. In both cases no `ifnone` function is being called. That would only happen if you passed a non-nil argument to `detect`.

Comment: you are not getting my point. you said - `if ifnone is set
    return ifnone.call`. In my case `ifnone` is `x` which is set to `nil`. so according to you `nil.call` should executed. But this is not the fact,actually it invokes `call` on `non nil` values. That's it.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu I also said "`nil` counts as not being set".

Comment: @iAmRubuuu There really is no such thing as an unset argument in Ruby. When people say that an argument has not been set, they mean that it's `nil`.